# How to add spring editing into config files

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am very new to spring. I saw some spring validations where the code was embedded into java source code. Im am trying to avoid this.

Is there a way to put the editing into the bean config file using properties.

For example @Size min=6 max=10 to

```
<bean id ="myvalidator" 
 class = "org.some.spring.class.blahblahblah"
<property name="min" value="6">
<property name="max" value="10">
<property name="errormsg" value=${error.msg}>
/>
```

or something to that effect

How do I associate @annotation to "com.some.spring.classname"

Comment: My advice: Use the annotations. The alleged purpose of external XML configuration was the ability to reconfigure without rebuilding the application, but that never actually happens in the real world; changing the XML requires the same steps as configuring with annotations and separates important information unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Validation annotations do not belong to Spring Framework, usually they come from the javax.validation package, sometimes, they come from a vendor, like hibernate ones for example.  Check the import statement to be sure about that.

So if your purpose of trying to get rid of the annotations is to not being dependant on any frameworks, unless you are using vendor specific validation annotations you shouldn't worry.

But anyways, if you still want to get rid of the annotations in your code and don't use any validation framework, one way is to create a Validator class elsewhere, and then use Spring for inject it whenever it is needed.

Let's say for example (i'm going to use JavaConfig style, because i'm not very familiar with XML)

```
@Component
public class MyValidator {
  // some validation code
}
```

In some configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationClass {
  @Bean
  public MyValidator myValidator() {
    return new MyValidator();
  }
}
```

And now you can inject with @Autowire an instance of your validator whenever you need it.

Edit: Btw, in this scenario, validation code should be coded manually, that is the price to pay if you want to get rid of the annotations.